# Operadores Bit a Bit C++

Tags: c++

Me gustaría saber por qué al usar el operador bit a bit en el código que adjunto a continuación se modifica el valor de la variable del primer bucle.

```
for(int c1 = 0; c1 < 4; c1++) {
        for(int c2 = -1*((c1*2+1)>>1); c2 < ((c1*2+1)>>1 + 1); c2++) {
            cout << c1 << endl;
```

[image: Salida]

Sin embargo al dividir entre 2 o multiplicar por 0.5 si obtengo una salida correcta.

Gracias

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Estaba pasando valores de un vector a una matriz en un orden específico, pero al hacerlo usando los operadores bit a bit, me di cuenta que se variaba el valor c1. Lo he arreglado cambiando >>1 por *0.5, pero me gustaría saber a que se debe que no se realice correctamente con el operador bit a bit.

Comment: Estas seguro de que el valor de `c1` no esta cambiando por el `c1++`?

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado donde estaba el error. Era necesario un cast para que entrase en la primera iteración.

El código quedaría asi:

```
for(int c1 = 0; c1 < 4; c1++) {
        for(int c2 = -1*((c1*2+1)>>1); c2 < ((int)((c1*2+1)>>1) + 1); c2++) {
            cout << c1 << endl;
```